# Getting one row from a nested array, push values into input then setTimeout to change to next array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, settimeout

I'm a beginner and it'll show :( but could anyone assist me into the right direction? I have an object literal with arrays nested inside. I need to grab the first row of arrays then push the values of that row into the three different inputs. Then after 5 seconds, it will timeout and then show the next array row. JSfiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/sqj3jz4p/

```
<div>
  <label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label> <input 
   type="number" class="count" id="votes1" readonly>
</div>
<div>
 <label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label> <input type="number" 
 class="count" id="votes2" readonly>
</div>
<div>
   <label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label> <input type="number" 
  class="count"  id="votes3" readonly>
</div>

var votingData = {
  voting: [
  [
    336122, 612446, 711326
  ],
  [
    4663122, 7001244, 822506
  ],
  [
    10437916, 12443910, 930971
  ],
  [ 
    17623004, 18680779, 1060304
  ],
  [
    24179347, 21991292, 1175930
  ]
 ]
};


function updateVoteCount(array) {
"use strict";
   for (var i = 0, l = votingData.voting.length; i < l; i++) {
   var voteArray = votingData.voting[i];
   console.log(voteArray);

    document.getElementById("votes1").value = voteArray[0];
    document.getElementById("votes2").value = voteArray[1];
    document.getElementById("votes3").value = voteArray[2];

  }
}


var timeDelayMs = 5000; // 5-second delay
   function voteUpdates(voting,myIndex) {
   "use strict";

   if ( voting.length > myIndex ) {
      updateVoteCount(voting[myIndex]);
      setTimeout(voteUpdates, timeDelayMs, voting, myIndex+1);
    }
  }

  voteUpdates(voting[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues on your code, such as the use of `setTimeOut` and the parameters for `voteUpdates` function. Take a look at a version of your code with fixes:

```js
var votingData = {
  voting: [
    [336122, 612446, 711326],
    [4663122, 7001244, 822506],
    [10437916, 12443910, 930971],
    [17623004, 18680779, 1060304],
    [24179347, 21991292, 1175930]]
};
   
function updateVoteCount(voteArray) {
  document.getElementById("votes1").value = voteArray[0];
  document.getElementById("votes2").value = voteArray[1];
  document.getElementById("votes3").value = voteArray[2];
}
  
var timeDelayMs = 5000; // 5-second delay

function voteUpdates(voting, myIndex) {
  if ( myIndex < voting.length) {
    updateVoteCount(voting[myIndex]);
    setTimeout(function() { voteUpdates(voting, myIndex+1) }, timeDelayMs);
  }
}

voteUpdates(votingData.voting, 0);
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label> <input 
   type="number" class="count" id="votes1" readonly>
</div>
<div>
 <label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label> <input type="number" 
 class="count" id="votes2" readonly>
</div>
<div>
   <label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label> <input type="number" 
  class="count"  id="votes3" readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the behavior you're looking for by calling `updateVoteCount` recursively:

```
var timeDelayMs = 5000; // 5-second delay
var nrows = votingData.voting.length;

function updateVoteCount(i) {

  var voteArray = votingData.voting[i];

  document.getElementById("votes1").value = voteArray[0];
  document.getElementById("votes2").value = voteArray[1];
  document.getElementById("votes3").value = voteArray[2];

  if (i < nrows - 1) {
    setTimeout(function() { updateVoteCount(i+1); }, timeDelayMs);
  }

}

updateVoteCount(0);
```

Each execution of the function will trigger the next after a specified delay until there are no more rows of data to read.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dz5dpk2/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```js
var votingData = {
  voting: [
    [
      336122, 612446, 711326
    ],
    [
      4663122, 7001244, 822506
    ],
    [
      10437916, 12443910, 930971
    ],
    [
      17623004, 18680779, 1060304
    ],
    [
      24179347, 21991292, 1175930
    ]
  ]
};


function updateVoteCount(position) {
 "use strict";

  document.getElementById("votes1").value = votingData.voting[position][0];
 document.getElementById("votes2").value = votingData.voting[position][1];
 document.getElementById("votes3").value = votingData.voting[position][2];
  
  if (position < votingData.voting.length) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     updateVoteCount(position+1)
    }, 5000)
  }
}

updateVoteCount(0)
```

```html
<div>
<label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label> <input type="number" class="count" id="votes1" readonly>
</div>
<div>
<label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label> <input type="number" class="count" id="votes2" readonly>
</div>
<div>
<label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label> <input type="number" class="count"  id="votes3" readonly>
</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to access the array in `updateVoteCount`, without any `for` loop.

Then you need simply hand over the array and the starting index.

```
voteUpdates(votingData.voting, 0);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    array
//                             ^ index
```

```js
function updateVoteCount(array) {
    document.getElementById("votes1").value = array[0];
    document.getElementById("votes2").value = array[1];
    document.getElementById("votes3").value = array[2];
}

function voteUpdates(voting, myIndex) {
    updateVoteCount(voting[myIndex]);  // you could move it outside of the condition
    if (myIndex + 1 < voting.length) { // check next index
        setTimeout(voteUpdates, timeDelayMs, voting, myIndex + 1);
    }
}

var votingData = { voting: [[336122, 612446, 711326], [4663122, 7001244, 822506], [10437916, 12443910, 930971], [17623004, 18680779, 1060304], [24179347, 21991292, 1175930]] },
    timeDelayMs = 5000; // 5-second delay

voteUpdates(votingData.voting, 0);
```

```html
<div><label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label><input type="number" class="count" id="votes1" readonly></div>
<div><label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label><input type="number" class="count" id="votes2" readonly></div>
<div><label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label><input type="number" class="count" id="votes3" readonly></div>
```

Comment: Ohhh ok. So when you call the function using the two arguments with the object property and the starting index of the array, which would be zero?

Comment: right, you need the array and the starting index. then you need to check if the next index is inside the array and invoke a timeout.